# Prove that $\min \{a^7,b^3,c^2,1\} \le abc$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

If $a,b,c$ are three non-negative real numbers, prove that:

$$\min \{a^7,b^3,c^2,1\} \le abc$$

I tried several ideas with the geometric mean:

$$\min \{a^7,b^3,c^2,1\} \leq \sqrt[4]{a^7b^3c^2}$$

but $\sqrt[4]{a^7b^3c^2} \leq abc$ is not true. I tried with other means but nothing significant. I think these ideas fail because the inequality is not homognenous.

Comment: Split into two cases: 1. $a,b,c \ge 1$ and 2. $\min(a,b,c) <1$. Also, if $x \in [0,1)$ then $x^{n+1} \le x^n$.

Answer (score 6):

Let our minimum be equal to $k$.

Thus, $$a^{42}\geq k^6,$$
$$b^{42}\geq k^{14},$$ $$c^{42}\geq k^{21}$$ and $$1\geq k.$$
Thus, $$(abc)^{42}\geq k^{6+14+21+1}$$ or
$$abc\geq k.$$

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of contradiction, assume that:

$$\min\{a^7,b^3,c^2,1\} > abc$$

Then:

$$a^7 > abc \Rightarrow a > (abc)^{\frac{1}{7}}$$

$$b^3 > abc \Rightarrow b > (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$c^2 > abc \Rightarrow c > (abc)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Also, because $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7} < 1$, we have:

$$1 > abc\Rightarrow 1 > abc^{1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{7}}$$

Multiplying these four inequalities, it follows that:

$$abc > (abc)^{\frac{1}{7}} \cdot (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot  (abc)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot abc^{1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{7}} = abc$$

a contradiction.

Comment: can make this a direct proof:  Let $k= \min(a^7,b^3,c^2,1)\le 1$ so $abc = (a^7)^{\frac 17}(b^3)^{\frac 13}(c^2)^{\frac 12}\ge k^{\frac 17}k^{\frac 13}k^{\frac 12}=k^{\frac{41}{42}}\ge k^1$

Comment: @fleablood, I think the proof is sufficiently direct (and natural) as is. It might seem verbose, because I wanted it to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

One can also grind through to get an answer:

If $a,b,c \ge 1$ or any of $a,b,c$ is zero then clearly the statement is true.

So we can suppose all are strictly positive and $\min (a,b,c) <1$.

If $a^7$ is the $\min$  then $a^{7 \over 5} \le b$ and $a^{7 \over 2} \le c$ so
$a^7 = a a^{7 \over 5} a^{7 \over 2} a^{11 \over 10} \le a a^{7 \over 5} a^{7 \over 2} \le abc$.

The same analysis mutatis mutandis applies to $b,c$.

Answer (score 0):

For a positive $a$ and $x>1$,
$$
min(a^x,1) \leq min(a,1) \leq a 
$$
Moreover, 
$$
[min(a,b,1)]^2 = min(a^2,b^2,1) \leq min(a,1) \, min(b,1) \, .
$$
This result is immediately extended to the case of three or more variables. Apply the two equations above to obtain
$$
min(a^n,b^n,...,h^n,1) \leq a b ... h 
$$
for $n>0$ variables $a...h$. The first equation tells you that
$$
min(a^{n_1},b^{n_2},...,h^{n_n},1) \leq a b ... h 
$$
when $n_1...n_n\geq n$.

Comment: This is not correct. If you take $a=b={1\over 2}$ then your second formula is false.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I corrected the wrong statement. I was trying to generalize the original question but actually my result is rather trivial and does not apply to the case in the original question (because it requires all the exponents to be bigger than 3 for three variables).